# How to make only one item of an accordion active at the time in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list with some items inside. After clicking on one item I would like to add class `active` to that item and close other items if there are any with class `active`. How can I achieve it?  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaysr6k7).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   lorem: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
    items: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", isActive: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", isActive: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", isActive: false },
      { text: "Build something awesome", isActive: false }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   toggleItem(item) {
        if(item.isActive) {
          this.items.forEach((item1) => {
            item1.isActive = false
          })
        } else
        if(!item.isActive) item.isActive = !item.isActive
      },
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
.item-active p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" @click="toggleItem(item)" :class="{active: item.isActive}">
     <h1 style="font-weight: bold">{{item.text}}</h1>
     <div v-if="item.isActive" class="item-active">
       <p>{{ lorem }}</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have only one thing that should be active at a time, you probably want to have a single variable that somehow indicates which item is active, instead of having to update all items in your accordion.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" @click="toggleItem(index)" :class="{active: isActive === index}">
      <h1 style="font-weight: bold">{{item.text}}</h1>
      <div v-if="isActive === index" class="item-active">
        <p>{{ lorem }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data () {
    return {
      lorem: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
      items: [
        { text: "Learn JavaScript" },
        { text: "Learn Vue" },
        { text: "Play around in JSFiddle" },
        { text: "Build something awesome" }
      ],
      isActive: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleItem(index) {
      this.isActive = index;
    },
  }
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
.item-active p {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```

Instead of looking on the item to see if it is active, we compare the index in our array to the item that should be active. We initialise that variable to null, which means by default none of them are open.

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I would also like to be able to close `active` item so none of the items are `active`.

Comment: Then either call `toggleItem` with `null` or check if `this.isActive` is already `index` and set it to `null` in that case.

Comment: So I made it like: `if(this.isActive === index) this.isActive === null` But it doesnt work.

Comment: Actually it works, just needed to use one `=` instead of `===`.

Answer (score 1):

hey attached the solution in jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hodca/xkq7dpy4/

```
  new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    lorem: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
    items: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", isActive: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", isActive: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", isActive: false },
      { text: "Build something awesome", isActive: false }
    ]
  },
 methods: {
toggleItem(item) {
      this.items.forEach((item1) => {
      if(item1.text == item.text){
            item1.isActive = !item1.isActive; 
      }else{
        item1.isActive = false
        }
      })
    },
```

}
})

Comment: Thanks! But I think the solution provided by @Sumurai8 is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
lorem: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
   items: [
     { text: "Learn JavaScript", isActive: false },
     { text: "Learn Vue", isActive: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", isActive: false },
  { text: "Build something awesome", isActive: false }
 ]
  },
methods: {
toggleItem(item) {
        let index = this.items.indexOf(item)

        this.items.forEach((item1) => {
        item1.isActive = false
      })
    this.items[index].isActive = true
   },
```

}
  })

try this, first find the index of selected item then put all "isActives" false , and at the end put the selected item "isActive" true